# Swift deleting entry with swipe from filtered search results

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uisearchcontroller

I can delete entries from unfiltered tableview,
but from filtered data with SearchController i get an error

```
reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (10)
```

I think the problem is to get the id from the filtered results?

My code is:

```
var NameFiltered = [String]()

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) {
            if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.delete) {
                    let id = ItemIDList[indexPath.row]
                    ItemNameList.remove(at: indexPath.row)
                    ItemIDList.remove(at: indexPath.row)
                    let deleteSQL = "DELETE FROM item WHERE item_id = '\(id)'"
                    itemTable.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
}
    }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if(SearchBarActive){
        return NameFiltered.count
    }

    return itemIDList.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cellIdentifier = "cell"

    var cell = self.exerciseManageTable.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier)
    if cell == nil {
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.subtitle, reuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier)
    }

    let name_data = itemNameList[indexPath.row]

    let groupname_data = itemGroupNameList[indexPath.row]
    cell!.detailTextLabel?.text = "group: \(groupname_data)"

    if(SearchBarActive){
        cell!.textLabel?.text = NameFiltered[indexPath.row]
    }else{
        cell!.textLabel?.text = name_data
    }
    return cell!
}
```

Comment: You need to show more code; specifically your `cellForRowAt` and `numberOfRowsInSection` but my guess is that you aren't deleting the data from the filtered results which caee there is a discrepancy between the number of rows in the array and the number expected as per the exception message

Comment: i added the code snippets now. You mean the entries should be also deleted from filtered arrays?

Comment: Yes, since `nameFiltered.count` will not reflect the deleted item.

Answer (score -1):

After deleting rows, add `self.tableView.reloadData()`.